# Apache Spark Machine Learning - can't get Estimator example to work

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am having difficulty taking any of the example machine learning code from the Spark docs and actually getting them to run as Java programs. Whether it's my limited knowledge of Java, Maven, Spark (or most likely all three) I can't find a useful explanation.

Take this [example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-estimator-transformer-and-param). To try and get this working I have used the following project structure

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── SimpleEstimator.java
```

The **Java** file looks like this

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;


public class SimpleEstimator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataFrame training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
      new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
      new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
    ), LabeledPoint.class);

    LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression();
    System.out.println("LogisticRegression parameters:\n" + lr.explainParams() + "\n");

    lr.setMaxIter(10)
      .setRegParam(0.01);

    LogisticRegressionModel model1 = lr.fit(training);

    System.out.println("Model 1 was fit using parameters: " + model1.parent().extractParamMap());

    ParamMap paramMap = new ParamMap()
      .put(lr.maxIter().w(20)) // Specify 1 Param.
      .put(lr.maxIter(), 30) // This overwrites the original maxIter.
      .put(lr.regParam().w(0.1), lr.threshold().w(0.55)); // Specify multiple Params.

    ParamMap paramMap2 = new ParamMap()
      .put(lr.probabilityCol().w("myProbability")); // Change output column name
    ParamMap paramMapCombined = paramMap.$plus$plus(paramMap2);

    LogisticRegressionModel model2 = lr.fit(training, paramMapCombined);
    System.out.println("Model 2 was fit using parameters: " + model2.parent().extractParamMap());

    DataFrame test = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(-1.0, 1.5, 1.3)),
      new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(3.0, 2.0, -0.1)),
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 2.2, -1.5))
    ), LabeledPoint.class);


    DataFrame results = model2.transform(test);
    for (Row r: results.select("features", "label", "myProbability", "prediction").collect()) {
      System.out.println("(" + r.get(0) + ", " + r.get(1) + ") -> prob=" + r.get(2)
          + ", prediction=" + r.get(3));
    }
  }
}
```

and the **pom** file as follows

```xml
<project>
  <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-estimator</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Estimator</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I then run `mvn package` from the root of this directory I get the following errors

```sh
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Estimator 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ simple-estimator ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ simple-estimator ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/src/main/java/SimpleEstimator.java:[15,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable sqlContext
  location: class SimpleEstimator
[ERROR] /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/src/main/java/SimpleEstimator.java:[44,22] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable sqlContext
  location: class SimpleEstimator
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.567 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-16T16:54:20+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/422M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project simple-estimator: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/src/main/java/SimpleEstimator.java:[15,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable sqlContext
[ERROR] location: class SimpleEstimator
[ERROR] /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/src/main/java/SimpleEstimator.java:[44,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable sqlContext
[ERROR] location: class SimpleEstimator
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

---

## Update

Thanks to @holden I made sure to add these lines

```java
// additional imports
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

// added these as starting lines in class
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Estimator");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
```

which progressed things a bit but now I get the following error

```sh
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project simple-estimator: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/philip/study/spark/estimator/src/main/java/SimpleEstimator.java:[21,36] no suitable method found for createDataFrame(java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint>,java.lang.Class<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint>)
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<A>createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<A>,scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag<A>) is not applicable
[ERROR] (cannot infer type-variable(s) A
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<A>))
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<A>createDataFrame(scala.collection.Seq<A>,scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag<A>) is not applicable
[ERROR] (cannot infer type-variable(s) A
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to scala.collection.Seq<A>))
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>,org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) is not applicable
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>)
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>,org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) is not applicable
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>)
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<?>,java.lang.Class<?>) is not applicable
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<?>)
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<?>,java.lang.Class<?>) is not applicable
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.List<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<?>)
```

The code referred to by the error is straight from the example

```
DataFrame training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
      new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
      new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
    ), LabeledPoint.class);
```

Comment: It has little to do with Maven. The `sqlContext` variable is undefined. I don't see any declaration of it on the example link either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to having the sql and spark contexts undefined as @holden mentioned, the Java example you refer to lacks a crucial step that converts the list of LabeledPoints into an RDD (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds for more information)

To take care of this, you can use `sc.parallelize` method from `JavaSparkContext` to convert the list into a `JavaRDD` object that the `createDataFrame` method expects as a parameter. See below snippet.

```
DataFrame training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
        Arrays.asList(
            new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
            new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
            new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
            new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
        )
    ), LabeledPoint.class);
```

Also, you need to specify Master URL in your code if you are running it standalone via maven. You may simply use `local[2]` as the URL to run Spark locally with 2 threads.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("Simple Estimator");
```

Normally, this would be provided to your program from the environment when using the `spark-submit` script. You can skip it if that is the case.

Finally you may want to disable the verbose log messages from Spark to follow the output from the algorithm much easier. You may skip this step as it is optional.

See the complete code below with all the mentioned modifications included.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

//ADDITIONAL IMPORTS FOR MUTING SYS.ERR
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SimpleEstimator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //MUTE LOG MESSAGES  FOR READABILITY (OPTIONAL)
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
                // keep empty
            }
        }));

        // added these as starting lines in class
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .setAppName("Simple Estimator");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

        DataFrame training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
                        new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
                        new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
                        new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
                )
        ), LabeledPoint.class);

        LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression();
        System.out.println("LogisticRegression parameters:\n" + lr.explainParams() + "\n");

        lr.setMaxIter(10)
                .setRegParam(0.01);

        LogisticRegressionModel model1 = lr.fit(training);

        System.out.println("Model 1 was fit using parameters: " + model1.parent().extractParamMap());

        ParamMap paramMap = new ParamMap()
                .put(lr.maxIter().w(20)) // Specify 1 Param.
                .put(lr.maxIter(), 30) // This overwrites the original maxIter.
                .put(lr.regParam().w(0.1), lr.threshold().w(0.55)); // Specify multiple Params.

        ParamMap paramMap2 = new ParamMap()
                .put(lr.probabilityCol().w("myProbability")); // Change output column name
        ParamMap paramMapCombined = paramMap.$plus$plus(paramMap2);

        LogisticRegressionModel model2 = lr.fit(training, paramMapCombined);
        System.out.println("Model 2 was fit using parameters: " + model2.parent().extractParamMap());

        DataFrame test = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(-1.0, 1.5, 1.3)),
                        new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(3.0, 2.0, -0.1)),
                        new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 2.2, -1.5))
                )
        ), LabeledPoint.class);

        DataFrame results = model2.transform(test);
        for (Row r: results.select("features", "label", "myProbability", "prediction").collect()) {
            System.out.println("(" + r.get(0) + ", " + r.get(1) + ") -> prob=" + r.get(2)
                    + ", prediction=" + r.get(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, you say that "You need to specify the Master URL", is this only when I intend to run the program using `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SimpleEstimator"`? Normally I don't specify it in the code itself, but instead run something like `bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleEstimator" --master local[4] ~/study/spark/estimator/target/simple-estimator-1.0.jar`

Comment: Correct. you do not need to specify in the code if you are specifying elsewhere.  It's `spark-submit` in your case. I'll update the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The examples generally leave out creating the `sqlContext` and `sc` (or SparkContext) as they would be the same for every example. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html has how to create a `sqlContext` and http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html has how to create a sc (or SparkContext).

You probably need something like:

Some more imports:

```
//Additional imports
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
```

Added at the start of your main method:

```
// In your method:
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
```

As per your update, the second issue that you are running into is that of creating the DataFrame (which is once again left out of the Java examples). The method you are trying to use is not yet implemented (in fact I have a pending pull request to implement something similar at https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/8779 although that version requires Row's and & Schemas, I've added a JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10720 to track adding this for local JavaBean solutions).

Thankfully, this extra step isn't all that much code we will take:

```
   DataFrame test = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(-1.0, 1.5, 1.3)),
      new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(3.0, 2.0, -0.1)),
      new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 2.2, -1.5))
    ), LabeledPoint.class);
```

And instead do:

```
   DataFrame test = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
      Arrays.asList(
        new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(-1.0, 1.5, 1.3)),
        new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(3.0, 2.0, -0.1)),
        new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 2.2, -1.5))
    )), LabeledPoint.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped move things on. My daily upvote limit is reached for today though. I'll be sure to upvote tomorrow