# Apache Spark - JavaSparkContext cannot be converted to SparkContext error

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm having considerable difficulty translating the Spark examples to runnable code (as evidenced by my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613413/apache-spark-machine-learning-cant-get-estimator-example-to-work)).

The answers provided there helped me with that particular example, but now I am trying to experiment with [the Multilayer Perceptron example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-ann.html#tab_java_0) and straight away I am encountering errors.

```java
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier;
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator;
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

// Load training data
public class SimpleANN {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "file:/usr/local/share/spark-1.5.0/data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt";
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple ANN");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, path).toJavaRDD();
  ...
  ...
  }
}
```

I get the following error

```sh
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project simple-ann: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/robo/study/spark/ann/src/main/java/SimpleANN.java:[23,61] incompatible types: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a SparkContext from your JavaSparkContext you can use the static method :

```
JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(youJavaSparkContextBean)
```

So you have to modify your code from

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, path).toJavaRDD();
```

To

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(
                                    JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(sc),
                                    path).toJavaRDD();
```